# Error when trying to install a module through the pip package manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging, python-3.9

I can't seem to install any package, I`ve been trying to install pygame especifically.
Although this problem only happens inside the virtual environment I made in VSCode, as in PyCharm It works perfectly, so I cannot figure out what is the root of the problem.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
          h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 1286, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 979, in send
          self.connect()
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\http\client.py", line 1458, in connect
          self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
          return self.sslsocket_class._create(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
          self.do_handshake()
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
      ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\cosas\Codedex\PythonNew\Game2\myenv\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\cosas\Codedex\PythonNew\Game2\myenv\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\cosas\Codedex\PythonNew\Game2\myenv\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-agsw97ml\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-agsw97ml\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-agsw97ml\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-agsw97ml\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 409, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\config.py", line 231, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds, auto_config=auto)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 479, in main
          and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 265, in ask
          update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 248, in update
          download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 116, in download_prebuilts
          download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
        File "C:\Users\Potato92\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-edkx1afg\pygame_e208b8a9623b45f2ae4642de1b7f3815\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 51, in download_sha1_unzip
          response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.11\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)>
```

Python version: 3.9.12
OS: Windows 10

I've tried reinstalling pip and even reinstalling Python entirely, but nothing seems to help. I found a post in a forum saying that in the latest Python versions there may be some problem with pip (At the time I was using Python 3.11), and so I installed and older version. Originally It seemed like it was gonna work, as It did work in PyCharm, but when I try to install any package in Visual Studio Code It shows me this error.

Comment: you have mingw installed in your system and added in your `PATH`, remove mingw folder from your `PATH` and try again.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I did and It still doesn't work, It's the same error too.

Comment: Then that means you didn't clean up the PATH correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your installing is written in your code.

If that's right, maybe you can try to do it in CMD or PowerShell console because VSCode sometimes runs the code differently from the original compiler.

here's the command:

```
pip install pygame
```

and make sure your python is added to the path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding trusted host flags to the pip install command, in your powershell.

```
pip install <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```